# Will SMTP be affected if port 23 is blocked on email server?

Tags: email-server

Currently our email firewall has port 23 opened. Our management has raised a concern on this port being opened and people could just telnet into our email firewall. Will it be a problem for inbound emails if port 23 is blocked for external users?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you really mean port 23 or did you mean port 25 ?

Comment: Port 23. One MTA to another MTA.. so does the source MTA uses telnet or just port 25 on both the source and destination port?

Answer (score 3):

No. The telnet port has nothing to do with SMTP.

Comment: Okay. I'm just a little confused over the transfer of emails from one MTA to another.

Comment: That uses SMTP, which is on port 25.

Comment: On both source and destination ? Thanks.

Comment: Well the source port in the packet will be random as usual but the service runs on port 25.

Comment: We are having a problem where people could just telnet into our email firewall port 25. That's where people can spoof emails and sent internally to our mail server. How can we solve that?

Comment: Uhm.. I think I get it now.. Can I just block telnet service all together for external users on my email firewall since it does not require such service?

Comment: If you block telnet service in your firewall, this will mean that connections to port 23 will be blocked. Port 25 will still be open for connections (the firewall won't care if they come from another SMTP, a telnet client, netcat or anything else). Of course you can block inbound connections to port 25 if you don't need to receive mails from the outside.

Comment: Blocking Telnet doesn't magically block SMTP, no. Again, they're unrelated.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to have port 23 open for mail purposes. Port 23 is not related to any of the mail protocols.

Having the port open on the firewall to the outside carries many other risks, but they're not limited to mail...

Comment: From 1 MTA to another, it does not require telnet? Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Port 25 is the norm.